# How to apply coupon on shipping fee in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop

I am trying to use wallet amount to purchase order, so I am creating a coupon code and applying on cart. but cart rule is not applied on shipping fee.

Comment: PrestaShop only allow coupons on product amount you can make shipping free but not offer discounts on shipping

Comment: You can use any third party module to accomplish this